# iOS app crashes by WatchDog but works when running from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm having a strange issue. I'm having an iOS Xcode (Generated by Unity 2019.3.0f6) project which runs perfectly fine when build and running straight from Xcode, on a physical device. But when I close it, and open that same app righting away on my device, the screen goes black for 20 seconds - than the app gets killed by the WatchDog. Did someone experience this before?

Comment: Do you have logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You app must be taking more time than the allowed time by iOS Watchdog service that's why it's killed by watchdog.
If you see logs like below with 'badf00d' code this is the reason.

> Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-update watchdog
>   transgression: application'<'com.xxx.development'>':416 exhausted real
>   (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds

Now you need to find the reason of delay in processing time and remove that delay to reduce loading/processing time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an answer to the question in general, but in my case I had to do with one of my Unity native plugins 'UniWebView' which had to be updated to work with the latest version of XCode again.